# Will turning of the power to a pc in sleep mode cause any problems?

Tags: windows, windows-8, sleep

I have a pc that whenever I go to sleep I need to save some programs in a way that I don't have to close them. So what I've been doing is putting my pc into sleep mode. This reacently caused it to turn on in the middle of the night for a few nights now.  So what I would do is to put it to sleeping mode and then turn of the power to the pc for around 5 seconds. This would put it in some kind of sleeping state whithout it rebooting itself.

But I dont know if this is healthy for my pc. Is it healthy? if not, how can I make my pc not reboot itself?

Comment: you have to specifically define the "sleep" modes your referring to?  Hibernation , or hybrid variations the computer can be in the off state. "Sleep" modes the ram is still loaded the programs are still running, and while most caches are probably flushed to disk, it is still pulling the power out from under it without being properly turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're doing hybrid sleep (suspend-to-RAM + suspend-to-disk; default in Windows) and power off it forcefully (so the suspend-to-RAM is "discarded" but you will still be restore from the suspend-to-disk).

I don't see that it will cause serious harm to the hardware. Still, why not just enable the hibernate option on the power menu?

[image]

Comment: Is that windows 10? I use 8.1 (Still have to update, I'm probebly the last men on earth that needs to do that)

Comment: Doesn't change these facts, AFAIK. But yes, it's Windows 10.

Comment: Yeah but the menu your're showing isn't the same. where can I find it in 8.1?

Comment: Oh you mean the power menu? It should be on the top-right corner after you press `Start` (or the Windows key). Also, as I've shown, if you are used to putting the computer to sleep with a sleep button, you can change the behavior of it instead / as well. Adding hibernate to the power menu isn't the only option.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why PC is waking up might be the incoming stuff from the network. You can disable this by going into Device manager, opening properties of the network adapter, then selecting "Power management tab" and unchecking "Allow this device to wake the computer".

Comment: I as sad as it may sound dont have internet on my pc

Comment: What Windows do you have?

Comment: i have windows 8.1